# Most efficient way to return search results based on keyword which is compared to multiple fields in an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-structures

I have a list of hundred objects. Each object has a structure similar to this:

```
Book {

title,

description,

author

}
```

In my web app, there is a search bar where upon input of a search term, I would like results of books to be displayed if the term is a part of the string value in any of the object fields.

Although there are a number of ways to go about this, what is the most efficient way?

Comment: what code have you already written, what all approaches have you tried?

Comment: I haven't written any code yet. The most basic approach I could think of was running a foreach loop and singling out the object with a condition like if(book.title.indexOf(searchterm)>=0 || book.description.indexOf(searchterm)>=0 || book.author.indexOf(searchterm)>=0). Although this would technically work, this wouldn't be best way to do it right?

Comment: but anyways you will have to loop over all the objects, at least once, I don't think that can be avoided

Comment: But could it be avoided if the objects were structured differently in combination with a data structure to reduce time complexity

Comment: you can take all of your objects and create some data structure over it , but that will again require iterating over the objects right?

Comment: Not really. With the right data structure, I could avoid iterating through them all and narrow down potential objects to search over. Like a binary search tree for example.

Comment: i am saying to create that data structure, yes in queries you can definitely avoid it, that is why i asked you to read about string matching problem

Comment: I could iterate over the list of objects the first time on the server side and send the data structure over to the client side where then it is a matter of iterating through the data

Comment: yes you can do it

Comment: Are you in favour of using Elastic search ?

Comment: I read up on it and from what I understood, it's a service that takes in raw data and organizes it using its own algorithm. If that is what you meant, then although a very interesting service, I would like to avoid integrating third party services, and build this one from scratch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to any how iterating over the objects. You can do it like this:

```js
var book = {name:'Name of the book',description:'This is a description', author:'this is a name of author' };

var keyword = 'is a';
var output={};

Object.entries(book).forEach(([k,v])=>{
  if(v.includes(keyword)) output[k] = v;
});

console.log(output);
```

You can also make use of `reduce` function here.